# maven gwt compile is failing

Tags: java, gwt, maven

My gwt compile invoked via maven is failing with exit code 1 and no other error message...

I have increased the memory allocation.

It simply says:

> [ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors
>
> [INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread

Is there any way I can look at logs or any other way to try and find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can look at logs or something? anything to try and find out what the problem is.

Run Maven with `-X` or `--debug` to enable debugging.  Otherwise, please include the entire output from Maven, as there may be some additional clues in it.

Answer (score 1):

A little embarrassing to admit but I should have just read the logs a bit better.

Problem is you like to see logs, so you turn the log level up to say TRACE or even SPAM...

At this log level there is so much coming through that you don't see the all important "[ERROR] indications!

2 lessons:

- When it doesn't compile, turn log level down to ERROR and recompile
- GWT compile does not fail fast

Comment: In a lot of cases it doesn't make sense to fail fast - lots of (poorly laid out) projects have issues where not all of the classes in their shared package can compile to JS correctly, but the ones that fail are not referenced in by the client, so their failure doesn't kill the full build. It isn't until late in compilation that the failure is a problem. Use the `-strict` flag to fail fast (in maven, `-Dgwt.compiler.strict=true`).